# Multiple cron expressions to trigger jenkins build

Tags: java, jenkins, cron

I would like to trigger a build based on two different sets of cron expressions.

Example:

- 1st expression: 8:00 AM, 5:00 PM
- 2nd expression: 12:30 PM

Let me know any suggestions.

Comment: Hi ! It would be better if you checkout [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1st expression: 8:00 AM, 5:00 PM 2nd expression: 12:30 PM
[image: 1st expression: 8:00 AM, 5:00 PM 2nd expression: 12:30 PM]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer helped me.