# Schedule periodic builds in jenkins till a specific date

Tags: jenkins, cron

I want to schedule periodic build in jenkins which should run **once daily at 9 am till a specific day** (example, if today is 1st of dec then it should run from 1st to 7th of dec only)

For running every day at 9 am the script is-

```
H 9 * * *
```

What should I add to run it till specific date only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cron expressions support range selectors. For your specific example, you can specify that it should run from the 1st to 7th of december only:

```
* 9 1-7 12 *

“At 09:00 on every day-of-month from 1 through 7 in December.”
```

You can easily test your expression [here](https://crontab.guru/#0_9_1-7_12_*). Since you can't specify the year in a cron expression, you will have to remove trigger manually afterwards.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. The website is really helpful.

Comment: just one more query. What about the transitioning month. Example- from 27th Nov to 3 Dec everyday 9 am

Comment: You can add multiple cron expressions in jenkins. I don't think you can add it in one expression. So this for this case, you could use `* 9 27-30 11 *` and `* 9 1-7 12 *`. See also this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44209349/2840115