# Multiple cron expressions using the job-dsl/pipeline syntax

Tags: jenkins, cron, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

In a Jenkins job config's *Build Triggers* section, it is possible to add multiple cron expressions separated on each line in the *Schedule* textarea e.g:

```
13 20 * * 0,1,2,3,4,5,6
13 8 * * 0,1,2,3,4,5,6
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44209349/1291886

How would one do this using the job-dsl/pipeline syntax?

Answer (score 18):

Using the job-dsl syntax:

```
triggers {
    cron('13 20 * * 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 \n 13 8 * * 0,1,2,3,4,5,6')
}
```

From the job-dsl documentation:

> To configure a multi-line entry, use a single trigger string with
>   entries separated by \n.

https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/freeStyleJob-triggers-cron

Answer (score 5):

I recommend changing the lines `13 20 * * 0,1,2,3,4,5,6` to `13 20 * * 0-6`, beauty in the details.

Answer (score 1):

As `cron` support string parameter, try this with string operation concat with next line (`\n`):

```
cron('41 12 20 10 *' + '\n 41 12 5 11 *' + '\n 41 12 15 11 *')
```